# print capital words in first column of file

Tags: files

I want my output :

```
VDD.
GND
AGNDSUB 
VMEASPOS.
VMEASNEG
VREFEXT
```

File1 having following information :

```
Power and signal 
VDD Digital Power This pin provides power supply connection for the digital
blocks.
GND Digital Ground This pin provides ground connection for the digital blocks.
AGNDSUB Ground This pin provides substrate connection.
VMEASPOS Digital Power Voltage to be measured.
VMEASNEG Ground Ground for the voltage to be measured.
VREFEXT Digital Power Reference voltage input of 1.024V %for VSENS calibration.
operating voltage
```

Comment: Where are the dots at the end of `VDD.` and `VMEASPOS.` meant to  come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `Gnu grep`:

```
grep -Eow '^[[:upper:]]+' file
```

Comment: `-w` is GNU extended.

Comment: @Gnouch, `-o` is a GNU extension. `-w` however though not standard is widespread and I believe predates GNU `grep`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I think that it's not so important what locale OP's computer is using as what OP wants to match. In a C/POSIX locale, the two example commands do the same thing. The first one works if it is desired to match the current locale's upper-case letters; the second one works if it is desired to match exactly the 26 upper-case ASCII letters.

Comment: Even in a typical `en_US.utf8` locale, `[A-Z]` matches `É` as well, and `Ý`, but not Ź. It's also been known to match `b` on some systems. Which is why I say that `A-Z` only makes sense in the POSIX/C locales where it is equivalent to `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: fair enough. Deleted.

Comment: Note that it doesn't match `ABC` (nor `ABC_DEF`) in `ABC_DEF ghi` (not clear if it should from the question though).

Comment: @Gnouc and @StephaneChazelas: By the way, http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=2.8+BSD&arch=default&format=html shows a manpage for Berkeley grep dating back to 1979; it includes the -w flag. I don't know why that never got into Posix. I think Stéphane's right about `-o` originating with Gnu; iirc, the original meaning of `-o` was what is now `-H`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The fact that `VMEASNEG` is written that way suggests that `_` are not going to appear in the terms. More to the point, it doesn't allow digits, which do appear to be important. But I think it's up to OP to adapt to their precise requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
awk '/^[A-Z]+\>/ { print $1 }' < data
```

`/^[A-Z]+\>/` [matches](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) complete words in capital letters at the start of the line. `{print $1}` then prints out the first field on those lines.

Comment: `\>` only works in some implement like `gawk`, `nawk`.

Comment: And matches at the transition between a `[[:alnum:]_]` and `[^[:alnum:]_]` (or the eol) while `$1` prints up to the first blank (or eol).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to tackle the problem.

You could print the first word as long as it contains only uppercase letters:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[[:upper:]]+$/ {print $1}'
```

(would print `VDD`, but not `VDD+DDV`)

print the first word as long as it doesn't contain lower case letters.

```
awk 'NF && $1 !~ /[[:lower:]]/ {print $1}'
```

That would print VDD+DDV or U.S.A. but not VDDfoo, but would print `+++`.

You could print the sequence of letters at the start of the line as long as they're all uppercase:

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]].*//;/^[[:upper:]]\{1,\}$/!d'
```

Or to ignore leading blanks:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[^[:alpha:]].*//;/^[[:upper:]]\{1,\}$/!d'
```

Would match `VDD` in `VDD+xxx` but not in `VDDxxx`

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -Mopen=locale -anle 'print $F[0] if /^[[:upper:]]+\b/' file 
VDD
GND
AGNDSUB
VMEASPOS
VMEASNEG
VREFEXT
```

Comment: Like for [Michael's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149821/22565), you're matching on the line until a word boundary but printing a field (so up to a blank). So, for instance, it would print `FOO.bar` for a line like `FOO.bar baz`.